# MYSQL QUERY, ALL ABOUT CONCAT

Tags: mysql, database, concatenation

This is my query

```
SELECT PART_NUM,DESCRIPTION, CONCAT('$',(ON_HAND*PRICE)) AS ON_HAND_VALUE
FROM part WHERE CLASS ='AP'
```

but when i tried to query it, my answers will be always equall to $0, its like the (ON_HAND*PRICE) is not working

these are the values :

```
Microwave Oven == 32*$165
GAS RANGE == 8*495
DISHWASHER ==8*595
DRYER ==12*349.95
WASHER ==128399.99
```

this must be the result:

```
PART_NUM----DESCRIPTION ---------ON_HAND_VALUE
CD52 -----------MICROWAVE OVEN----$5280
DR93----------- GAS RANGE-----------    $3960
KT03----------- DISHWASHER-----------   $4760
KL62----------- DRYER-----------    $41994.4
DW11----------- WASHER-----------   $4799.88
```

Comment: What is the data_type of `ON_HAND`, `PRICE` fields?

Comment: @bpgergo the ON_HAND is int and the PRICE is varchar

Comment: Honestly looks good to me; but several examples I've run across use format to handle possible fractional situations. CONCAT('$',FORMAT(ON_hand*price),2))  HUMOR: side note: that's one expensive washer (128399.99 should be 12*399.99)  perhaps bpgergo is on the right path though and one isn't numeric.

Comment: You can't do math with varchar you have to cast it to numeric.  so something like CONCAT('$',(ON_HAND*cast(PRICE, Decimal(10,2)))

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, the reason this isnt working is that the result of (On_Hand*price) is erroneous (you are multiplying a number with a string)

On the other hand, if on_hand is an `int` and price is a `decimal/double/float` then you can get the correct result by using the following:

```
CONCAT('$',convert(ON_HAND*PRICE,char))
```

if PRICE is a `varchar` i would strongly suggest to store it as a `decimal` before continuing. This problem you are experiencing is just the start of headaches you will have if you store prices as `varchar`s.

if this is not possible, then you can look at the Cast() function to first cast your `varchar` as a `decimal` or `float` before performing the multiplication.

EDIT:

MySQL appears to be smart enough to convert varchars to floats itself, however it WONT work when there is a '$' sign in the varchar field.

So maybe try doing the following:

```
CONCAT('$',convert(ON_HAND*Right(PRICE,Length(Price)-1),char))
```

Comment: the problem here is the '$' sign you are storing in the Price field.

Comment: That's because price is still a varchar, you need to cast it to decimal 1st.

Answer (score 0):

You see, you get strange results if you try to multiply an int with a varchar.
try this

```
CONCAT('$',CAST(PRICE,int)*ON_HAND)
```

or this

```
CONCAT('$',CONVERT(PRICE,int)*ON_HAND)
```

docs http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html

Comment: This is what i get sir :(

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'int)*ON_HAND) AS ON_HAND_VALUE FROM PART LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: OK, first things first. Does this one works fine? `SELECT PART_NUM,DESCRIPTION, CAST(PRICE,int) as int_price, ON_HAND FROM part WHERE CLASS ='AP'`

Comment: If first select worked, for second, try this one `SELECT PART_NUM,DESCRIPTION, (CAST(PRICE,int)*ON_HAND) as ON_HAND_VALUE FROM part WHERE CLASS ='AP'`